# Music21: Getting Roman numerals for all chords in score, factoring in key changes and unspecified keys

Tags: python, music21

I'm trying to get a Roman numeral analysis of lots of MusicXML scores, many of which include key changes. I had originally tried using ChordSymbols--they seem to be easier to access--and then transpose to Cmaj/Amin, but since it turns out that ChordSymbols can't be transposed, I'm now trying to use Roman numerals. I can't figure out, though, how to collect a list of these in a score that has key changes. I also have problems with scores and parts of scores that have unspecified key signatures (i.e., Cmaj/Amin).